# Why transfinite induction only works on well-ordered set?

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-induction

Could you please help me to know why transfinite induction only works on well-ordered set and not arbitrary set ? Why the fact that every susbset has a least element is necessary for transfinite induction principle ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do well-founded recursion and/or induction on any well-founded relation.  See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Well-Founded_Recursion).  I'm not sure how you expect to do recursion or induction on a set with no additional structure.

Comment: What does "induction" mean to you?

Comment: Imagine total order which is not a well order, i.e. there is a nonempty subset $S$ which does not have a minimum. Now convince yourself that the predicate $P(x):=x\not\in S$ satisfies the conditions for transfinite induction, yet it is not true for all $x$ (as $S$ is nonempty). So, transfinite induction doesn't work without well ordering.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Hi, thanks for your comment. I don't really understand your point. Could you please explain why "$S$ is non empty" leads to "it is not true for all $x$", and why eventually it confirms that the transfinite induction does not work ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JohnDoe: Hi, thanks for your comment. In fact, I just wonder why well-ordered set is needed for transfinite induction to work. Maybe totally ordered is enough (I know it is wrong). Why there is a least element for each subset make transfinite induction to work ? Could you please send sometime to answer it ? Many thanks.

Comment: Hello all, sorry, i don't understand why my question is down voted. I think it is not trivial the question, and it is not "without thinking" also. In my point of view, it is a legitime question that not deserves your down votes.

Comment: Well, $P(x)$ means "$x$ is not in $S$". So because there _are_ some elements in $S$, the statement $(\forall x)P(x)$ is wrong. Yet, it follows from transfinite induction. So transfinite induction must be broken. (How does it follow? Use the contrapositive. Let $P(x)$ be false. So $x\in S$. So, as $S$ has no minimum, in total order, there is an element $y<x, y\in S$. But then $P(y)$ is false too, and therefore $(\forall y<x)P(y)$ is also false. Thus, $(\forall y<x)P(y)\implies P(x)$ is true for all $x$. Thus, transfinite induction would imply $(\forall x)P(x)$.)

Answer (score 3):

I will expand here on my comment. Let $(X,\le)$ be a totally ordered set. We will prove that it is necessary for the order relation $\le$ to be a well ordering, if we want the transfinite induction to work.

Suppose, otherwise, that $S$ is a nonempty subset of $X$ which does not have a minimum. The predicate $P(x):=x\not\in S$ is therefore not true on the entire $X$ (as $S$ is nonempty), in other words $(\forall x)P(x)$ is false. Yet, $P$ satisfies the condition for transfinite induction:

$$(\forall y<x)P(y)\implies P(x)$$

This is true if $x\not\in S$ (as the consequent is true), but is *also* true if $x\in S$ !!! Namely, as $x$ is not the minimum of $S$ and the ordering is total, there is a *smaller* $y\in S, y<x$, and then $P(y)$ is false, and the entire implication is vacuously true.

In other words, transfinite induction didn't work - it proved a false statement $(\forall x)P(x)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I understand how transfinite induction can fail on a non well-ordered set, but I'm still not clear why should it be well-ordered set but not other "type" of set ? (like we scan every type of set, then we claim that only well-ordered sets can guarantee the transfinite induction). Could you please have a look at it ? Thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I am afraid I don't understand what you are asking me. Isn't it enough that we cannot be sure that transfinite induction doesn't work if the ordering is not a well ordering? Like, if you are not sure your car would work on kerosene, you won't put it into your tank. However, quite often you are just working with a set you know in advance is well ordered (say, $\mathbb N$) and then you "just" use transfinite induction, knowing that it works (or ordinary induction, which is on $\mathbb N$ equivalent to transfinite).

Answer (score -1):

Let's keep things simple. As any induction, transfinite induction requires two ingredients : 1) order, because the main point of induction is "statement $n$ $\Rightarrow$ statement $n+1$", and 2) a base case (e.g. $n = 0$).

Indeed, without an initial statement, the chain of induction can't be true, because each step depends on the previous one, but a starting point is needed.

In consequence, in a more general context, the set indexing the statements requires a total order to ensure the first ingredient and a minimal element to represent the starting point of the chain of induction, hence well-order. Moreover, in the case of transfinite induction, each limit ordinal corresponds to a new starting point.

Comment: A well-order is more than just a total order with a minimum element.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  I know, I said I wanted to keep things simple. Moreover, OP mainly asked about the least element, whose purpose doesn't require much than common sense in the end.